# How to plot cumulative stock return using Excel data?

Tags: list-manipulation, finance, excel

I have an Excel file with daily prices and  returns of a number of stocks.

I need to plot a cumulative return for each stock.

How can i do this, using `Excel data`, but not [`FinancialData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html) command?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, you should note that you simultaneously asked this question at Wolfram Community (http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/936881).

Comment: 1) What do you mean by cumulative. 2) Give a little sample of your cvs file with just some lines

Answer (score 3):

Importing data from excel:

```
values = Import["C:\\Users\\LMC\\Desktop\\file.xlsx"]
```

> ({
>     {{15.}, {20.}, {80.}, {95.}, {45.}}
>    })

The function you want is [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html):

```
ac = Accumulate@Flatten[values]
```

> {15., 35., 115., 210., 255.}

To plot data use [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html):

```
ListPlot[ac]
```

[image]